# Prevent from regain focus if app is in background

Tags: android, android-asynctask, focus

I am writing an application where using an AsyncTask. Once it is done it launches another Activity.

Now if AsyncTask gets started and if the Home button is pressed, then on finish next Activity gets launched (which is fine) but app also comes into foreground again.

How can I prevent App to regain focus?

Comment: You can add a simple check in the OnCreate of  the new activity to check if the app is active or not, it not, minimize the activity. That's all which can be done for now. It will open for a microscopic part of sec though. Can be seen in slow phones.

Comment: @Tushar minimize can be done..but to detect activity is in background only thing we have onPause/resume event. and these method have their multi event source to trigger.. Any other suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting a check in the next Activity, you can put the check in the first Activity. Simply set a flag when the first Activity executes onPause() and in the onPostExecute() of the AsyncTask check the flag. If the flag is set, it means that onPause has already been called in the meanwhile. So, you don't start the new Activity. If flag is not set, it means that the user has not navigated away and you can start the next Activity.